# "Directory Deployment" Glassfish + Maven + Eclipse

Tags: deployment, maven, directory, glassfish, redeploy

**Background:**
I have project hibernate + spring + wicket configured by Maven2. To be more specific by m2eclipse.

**What is the problem:**
My problem is each time I have to make: clean, install and build (redeploy/deploy), what takes a lot of time. I was trying to make "Directory Deployment" which is described [here](http://www.techjini.com/blog/2007/10/23/glassfish-auto-deployment-and-hot-deployment/). I hoped that I will only has to make clean and install to deploy my application to glassfish.

Unfortunately i got:

> WARNING : deploydir command deprecated.  Please use deploy command
>   instead.

also when I changed something in .java files I had to make manual deploy. Directory Deploy didn't work.

**Question:**
Is there any way to make deploy/redeploy faster ? Maybe start to use ant, not maven. Maybe someone use "deploydir" with success. Maybe redeploy by eclipse (not maven/m2eclipse) ?

I'm really tired of waiting for redeploy. I will be thankful for any advice.
 
Adam

Answer (score 0):

You could give a try to JRebel. If you do not want to pay for it, the only thing you can do is to fit the deployment process of Eclispe webtools platform. So basicly you need to install m2extras as well (not only m2eclipse, since wtp integration is in extras at a different update site), and define every single configuration eclipse needs to use deploy mechanism. Then define a server in eclipse, add your project to the server, and it will work.